# My thumbnails are not going into multiple columns, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So at the moment I am working on a website (I'm using Bootstrap 3 to style my site). On the homepage, I am wanting to have a series of thumbnails which give title and brief description on different parts of the site. I have been able to program this, but I am also wanting to have the thumbnails be in four columns in a row however it pops up as four rows in a column. I am using the classes, row and col-md-4 from bootstrap and from what I see, that should automatically put the thumbnails into rows of four.

Can anyone think of what I may be doing wrong? Please ask questions on what I have written if you need to know more details.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code Cavanagh

Comment: Could you put an example of what you have done on something like http://jsfiddle.net/ so that it is easier to see what has gone wrong?

Comment: Sure! I added all all of the tags used in the section of the page. It doesn't look exactly like it does on my editor but you should be able to work with it. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/shabowow/5wpx87k1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap 3 is designed to be used with multiple screen resolutions out of the box.  As such, depending on the size of the screen the content is restructured to either take the full available width or the preset width.

In your case you need the a single row with four columns, I suspect this is due to the fact that screen you are viewing the page in, or the width of the container is less than the `md` size width (Greater than or Equal to 992px - see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

As such, you can either use one of the lower resolution prefixes (`sm` or `xs`) or increase the width of the container.

See the example fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/ay3oL496/ - for clarification on how the screen resolution affects the various `col-` classes.  Increase the width of the preview tab, and the various elements should resize.

**// Update following code sample**

Thanks for the code sample - the problem is clear now.  See the solution at - http://jsfiddle.net/x6vqrck9/1/.

The issue you are experiencing is due to the `<div class="row">` syntax that is added after each column - effectively you have one column per row.  In addition, you are using `col-md-4` - this will result in 3 columns per row (There are twelve grid columns, and you are using 4 to display each element).

The structure should be

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">Content here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Content here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Content here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Content here</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">Other site content here</div>
</div>
```

The code in the fiddle corrects these issues aswell as adding the jQuery, and bootstrap libraries.

Comment: I tried playing around with the different classes but no luck. My laptop has a 1280x800 resolution as well. Thanks though!

Comment: @SebastianHans Thanks for the code sample, I can see the problem now. Answer updated.